# Generic type for data transfer records in Haskell

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, dto

I want to exchange data with some remote system (can be via HTTP, a database, files, etc.), and therefore create data transfer objects (DTOs) - basically, records that can be serialised and deserialised easily. In a second step, I want to map these DTOs to my domain objects.

All DTOs have an ID field (e.g., a technical primary key, a message identifier, or a file name). Because this is a general pattern, I try to capture it in a general type. This is my first attempt:

```
data DtoShell = DtoShell
   { id :: UUID
   , dto :: Dto}

data Dto
   = MyDto1 ConcreteDto1
   | MyDto2 ConcreteDto2
   | ...
```

In this way, functions that are concerned with handling arbitrary DTOs, and therefore only need the ID, can deal with the `DtoShell`only but do not need to care about the actual data inside. Functions that are particular to a specific DTO can work with that. In between, there must be some "dispatcher" function that pattern-matches on the concrete type and selects the appropriate function - for example, to map a concrete DTO to its corresponding domain type.

However, this scheme is hard to extend - if there ever is a new `ConcreteDto3`, I need to change the above code, and I need to change the "dispatcher" function.

I do see that this seems to be a representation of some more fundamental problem (the expression problem? I am not a CS major...). In my search, I came across potential solutions: Phantom types, existential types, and, foremost, typeclasses. But I am not yet proficient enough in Haskell and general abstract CS to value the pros and cons of each approach. Thus, I have two questions:

1. Is there a general, accepted practice or pattern how to model such "identifiable records"? E.g., when accessing relational databases.
2. Is there a single resource (book, paper, tutorial) that compares the different approaches to data abstraction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just create a parametrically polymorphic envelope?

```
data Envelope a = Envelope { eid :: UUID, edata :: a } deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)
```

This is basically just a specialised pair (two-tuple), so you make it an instance of all the type classes that `(,)` is an instance of. Here I've made it a `Functor` instance by using the `DeriveFunctor` language extension.

Comment: Once again, thanks very much for the helpful comments that get me closer to really understanding FP - step by step.